# How fix Stacks to top and bottom using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

how are you ?

I need to fit all the content of first zstack (I use two zstack to add a transparent layer over first zstack background) to window size and if the user scroll down, shows additional stacks added below.

I add Spacer() to push the last HStack to bottom and before stacks to the top (in middle must be a dynamic blank space) of window without result.

Can help me please ?

Thanks

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ZStack {
                bgColors[weatherDescription]
                ZStack {
                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(hex: 0x212121, alpha: 0.5), Color(hex: 0x212121, alpha: 0.5)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        Text("Hello!")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding(.top, 20)
                            .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        Text("Hello!")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.title)
                            .padding(.bottom, 1)
                        Text("Hello!")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        
                        HStack(alignment: .center, content: {
                            Text("TEXT1")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.title3).fontWeight(.bold)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            Text("TEXT2")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.title3).fontWeight(.bold)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                        Spacer()

                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30, content: {
                            Text("Text1")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 90))
                            Text("Text2")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .animation(.easeIn)
                        }).frame(width: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)

                    }.padding() // vstack
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // zstack
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) // zstack

         // ADITIONALS STACKS VISIBLES ONLY WHEN SCROLL DOWN

        }
```

Comment: Try adding a padding of `.padding(.bottom, UIScreen.main.bounds.height)` to the `ZStack`. If your view does not take up the entire screen, you might need GeometryReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just used so many codes, I edited them to less code, here for example you just used so many **foregroundColor** which you can see in my code I used just one time on parent View.

Also we can not use ScrollView like you used it! ScrollView needs Content to Scroll, you have less Content.

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                
                Text("Hello!")
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .font(.largeTitle)

                
                Text("Hello!")
                    .font(.title)

                
                Text("Hello!")
                    .font(.title3)
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("TEXT1")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)

                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("TEXT2")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)

                }

                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Text1")
                        .font(.system(size: 90))
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Text2")
                        .font(.caption)

                }
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .animation(.easeIn)

    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem if is I put all your code inside Scrollview, the spacers has no effect.

Comment: @user2398236: You should not be sorry for leaning, I am learning with you together, ScrollView has that Behavior and it ignores Space but it works with Text and other Views.